# Creating a function to call an API multiple times with unique inputs (PRAW reddit api)

Tags: python, function, api, reddit, praw

Beginner here. I am working on a Reddit API (PRAW) project in which I am attempting to aggregate data from multiple subreddits.

In order to achieve this now, I am writing a line for each subreddit in which I want to query and it works, but I would really like to write a piece of code that takes in a list of subreddit names and performs the call for each item in the list instead of me having to add lines of code.

The list of subreddits would eventually be user-defined and read in from a google sheet or similar entry point.

My code now

```
#Authenticate for Reddit
r = praw.Reddit(client_id='id',
                client_secret='secret',
                user_agent='agent')

#call new posts from multiple subreddits with no limit

posts = [] #empty container for df
toyota = r.subreddit('Toyota').new(limit=None)
tundra = r.subreddit('ToyotaTundra').new(limit=None)
tacoma = r.subreddit('ToyotaTacoma').new(limit=None)
prius = r.subreddit('Prius').new(limit=None)
runner= r.subreddit('4Runner').new(limit=None)
highlander = r.subreddit('ToyotaHighlander').new(limit=None)

#compile into list

lists = list(itertools.chain(toyota,tundra,tacoma,prius,runner,highlander))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a simple input loop:

```
x = int(input()) #user inputs how many submissions he plans to do
posts = []
for y in range (0,x):
    a = input()
    subposts = r.subreddit(a).new(limit=None)
posts.append(subposts)
```

You may deal with the data the way you prefer, but the general idea is that you can put the info you get from each subreddit everytime the loop runs.